# Memory model of template function inside non-template class?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, member-functions

Suppose I have:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    //Do something with T
};
```

I know that the compiler will generate a `class A<T>` for each different `T` defined in the code.

What if I have:

```
class B
{
    template <typename T>
    void f() { /* Do something with T */ }
};
```

Would there be only one definition of `class B` but multiple overloads of `f()` for each different `T` it's called with?

Comment: Yes.  What else could it be?

Comment: Om Assembly level there is no class definitions. Every class method is compiled to global function with hidden "this" parameter. Templated function is compiled to global function for every instantiated type, in every compilation unit.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Class with templated member function, is the same class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121910/class-with-templated-member-function-is-the-same-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with every instantiation of `f<T>` there will be a definition of `f()` generated by compiler.
Depending on the compiler, the `f()` could be optimized due to inlining or it can just acquire that much space in the code segment.

However, I have seldom came across this kind of design where you have a non-static template member function (without any argument!) inside a non-template class.